# Delete something through relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 4 models. I want to delete question, but now i cant. Dont why know. I think, firstly i need delete answer on this questions, then delete inquiry, and then questions itself. Right. But how i can do it?

there my models:

-respondents_model

```
class Respondent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries
  has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries
  has_many :answers,   :through => :inquiries
end
```

-answer_model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inquiry
  belongs_to :question

  validates_uniqueness_of :inquiry_id
end
```

-question_model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer, :through => :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy
end
```

-inquiry_model

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :respondent
  has_one    :answer
end
```

and my question_controller

```
  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    head :ok
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to delete answers, because they will be automatically deleted as far as you set `:dependent => :destroy`. So you just need to call:

Also you need to specify WHAT EXACT question are you going to destroy: `Question.find params[:id]`

```
def destroy
  @question = Question.find params[:id]
  @question.destroy
  head :ok
end
```

Comment: Thank for fast response!! but it doesn't work:S i cant get why. in console : SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE (`questions`.`id` = 0).. hmm

Comment: I tried to delete question... i wrote in controller what you gave me.. and still same ;( maybe i something missed?

Comment: Think so. What do you writing in console?

Comment: Nono, i didnt write in console, i make scaffold for question. and lick on destroy link.. and so.. ERROR and in console i get : Processing QuestionsController#destroy (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-15 14:12:56) [DELETE]
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2eqggpHA+CYezL2g4wQX7iUieD+xZa7mA/UqR9oBi1I=", "id"=>"undefined"}
  Question Columns (0.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `questions`
  Question Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE (`questions`.`id` = 0)

Comment: You should read some basic about Rails, man. You didn't send `id` of the quesition to the server: `"id"=>"undefined"`. So your link, that you have just clicked, is wrong.

Comment: Is that valid ruby code ? 
`@question.find params[:id]; @question.destroy`. I don't so. Should be atleast: `@question = Question.find(params[:id]); @question.destroy`

Comment: yep, my fault. But it isn't issue here

Comment: 2Tumtu: thank you!
2fl00r: i read it, hm but look, i if just creating scaffold, i can delete easily, but when I begin using relationship table i cant delete rows, but can add